# preg_replace Text in Email Link

Tags: php, preg-replace

I have a php string

```
echo $this->contact->email_to
```

This outputs the following HTML

```
<a href="mailto:me@mymail.com">me@mymail.com</a>
```

I want it to output the following HTML

```
<a href="mailto:me@mymail.com">&#xf0e0;</a>
```

I have been playing around with preg_replace but getting nowhere. I have got as far as the following code but it doesn't work at all.

```
echo preg_replace(array('/([\w-?&;#~=\.\/]+\@(\[?)[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?))/i'), array('$1', '&#xf0e0;'), $this->contact->email_to);
```

I am no PHP expert so I understand there might be easier ways of doing this but I am having difficulty figuring it out.

Comment: Do you have the option of modifying the output of `$this->contact->email_to`? You could simply output the email address, use it in your own anchor tag, and then use whatever you want for the text.

Comment: Hi Kacey, no I'm afraid not. I'm stuck with what I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the **best** way of doing this, but using `preg_replace` with HTML tags, and especially emails is always a pain in the butt. Let me know if this works for you:

```
echo preg_replace("/\>(.*)\@(.*)\</i", ">&#xf0e0;<", $this->contact->email_to);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I'm afraid this didn't work.

Comment: Just the same `<a href="mailto:me@mymail.com">me@mymail.com</a>`

Comment: Interesting. Check out [this codepad](http://codepad.org/dGNvYBVI) I set up using the code I gave you. It works this way. The output replaces the text in the anchor tag. Maybe there's something different about your HTML output?

Comment: Hi Kacey, you are absolutely correct, this does work. There is something else at play here which is preventing it from working on my site but your answer is correct, thank you.

Comment: You could try running a str_replace on the email output first to replace all spaces, and then try the preg_replace. There might be an added space in there somewhere that is messing up the code.